# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-savedstate

The following is my stack trace :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
```

This is my code :

```
dialog = FeedDialog.getInstance(feedViewModels, this, false, this);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager != null && !isFinishing()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, dialog);
            ft.addToBackStack("unread_feeds");
            ft.commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
```

Here dialog is a fragment which contains a view pager.

The issue has appeared only once. Let me know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`IllegalStateException` occurs when you are invoking a method at an inappropriate time.

A very common way when this appears is where you invoke a network call, and trigger a fragment transaction in the callback. If the app is minimised when the network call completes, you should get an `IllegalStateException`.
I think you should be performing this transaction in some async callback.

Solution is to add an `isResumed()` check before performing the transaction. If `isResumed()` returns false, you will need to queue the transaction to occur after app is resumed. You can have a helper method in your Fragment (or BaseFragment) that maintains a list of `Runnable` objects and executes them in `onResume`.

```
List<Runnable> pendingJobsOnResume;
public void executeOnResume(Runnable runnable) {
    if (isResumed()) {
         runnable.run();
    } else {
         pendingJobsOnResume.add(runnable);
    }
}

// And invoke them in onResume
void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    for (Runnable runnable : pendingJobsOnResume) {
        runnable.run();
    }
    pendingJobsOnResume.clear();
}
```

Then in your callback, you can pass the transaction code through a runnable to `executeOnResume` instead of directly invoking.

```
someAsyncTask(new Callback() {
    void call() {
        // do common stuff.

        executeOnResume(new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                // fragment transaction
            }
        })
    }
}
```